# Android QR code referral

Tags: android, cookies, qr-code

Is there a way how to link user to application installation via QR code?

Lets say that I have a user with ID 1002. I would generate a link http://app.com?ref=1002 and store its value to a QR code.

Then the user would show this QR code to his friend, his friend would scan it and open a GET request to my web server and redirect him to the google play.

When the new user has installed the app I would like to link him to the user who invited him.

Is there a way how to achieve that? Maybe set some cookie and upon first application lunch open the browser again verifying whether there is some cookie.

Would this work? Is there a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22561636-How-Google-Play-Install-Referrer-Works

Basically you need to add you tracking ID to google play url.
Then when app installs, collect the same from google play.

You will need to add a receiver in you app, filtering this

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
```